# Calculation amount or number of certain pixel-values in a raster

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1

It seems pretty simple but until now I could not find a proper solution:
In a given raster i want to know the number or ratio of e.g. red pixels.

Edit: 
to be more precise: I have a number a arial photos and want to estimate vegetation cover, so I tried to estimate/count the number or amount of green pixels. If there is an other solution to estimate vegetation cover, i am open to any other way.

First Attemps were raster statistics and inspecting histogramms, but the results were not clear to me.

Comment: ArcGis 10.1 or Qgis 2.2

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Aaron.  Would you mind re-posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

One of the most basic methods of estimating vegetation cover is to first calculate [NDVI](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t00000052000000) (assuming you have a near infrared band and a red band in your imagery). The formula is:

```
(nIR-red)/(nIR+red)
```

Then [threshold the image](http://www.mathworks.com/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexndvi.html) by creating a binary raster dataset, usually via the [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) or [Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) tool. Once you have a binary raster dataset, simply calculate the number of 1's vs 0's.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have only RGB channels, this is the reason why i want to use only the colour.

Comment: If you are in the USA, you can download 4-band imagery for large portions of the US.  See Earth Explorer.